# In-casesensitive PHP search?

Tags: php

So, I'm trying to search for specific words / values in a text file.

Currently, I can only search it case sensitive.

Here's my code:

```html
<html>
<?php
 //$searchthis = "ignore this";
 $matches = array();
 $FileW = fopen('result.txt', 'w');
 $handle = @fopen("textfile.txt", "r");
 ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
 if ($handle)
 {
  while (!feof($handle))
  {
   $buffer = fgets($handle);
   if(strpos($buffer, $_POST["search"]) != FALSE)
    $matches[] = $buffer;
  }
  fwrite($FileW, print_r($matches, TRUE));
  fclose($handle);
 }
 print 'Found Possible Matches, here are the results' ."\n";
 sleep(2);
 //show results:
 sleep(10);
?>
 </br>
<?php
    $file = "result.txt";
    $text = file_get_contents($file);
    $text = nl2br($text);



    echo $text; 
?>

</html>
```

So, instead of doing this:

Query for search: casesensiTiveworD
Result: Nothing

when there's a value in textfile.txt that's "casesensitiveword"

I want it to do this:

Query for search: casesensiTiveworD

Result: Casesensitiveword

But I don't know how to do this, I'd appreciate any help, I've been trying to figure this out for hours now and I can't.

Comment: Use [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following line ...

```
if(strpos($buffer, $_POST["search"]) != FALSE)
```

with this one ..

```
if(stripos($buffer, $_POST["search"]) !== FALSE)
```

function **'stripos'** ignores case sensitivity check

Comment: @Ryan why not? You haven't searched.. its [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)